# how to multiple space lines in the output file in C++

Tags: c++, string, newline

##### Adding Multiple New Lines to a String

Is there a more appealing syntax — or a syntax that is less repetitive — for inserting multiple `new lines` into a string than the two methods I use, *which are*...

###### #1 |   `cout << "\n\n\n";`

###### #2 |   `cout << endl << endl << endl;`

Comment: isn't \n short enough?

Comment: dear Bathsheba, the thing is that for instance if want to have 5 space lines in my output files, do I have to write five times "\n", or there is any other command?

Comment: Bear in mind that `std::endl` doesn't just put a newline character. It also flushes. You probably don't want to do `<< std::endl << std::endl`. If you really want to flush the stream as well, you should probably do `<< "\n\n" << std::flush`. Also, is this really what you want to do, or could you just pipe the output through `sed G`? Just another possibility; might not be applicable.

Comment: @BoBTFish You mean `<< "\n\n\n" << std::flush`, right?

Comment: @H2CO3 Well my example used `endl` twice, so `"\n\n"` is equivalent (modulo flushing). Up to the OP to decide how many lines they want.

Comment: @BoBTFish Originally you wrote: "if you really want to flush the stream as well, you should probably do `<< std::endl << std::endl << std::flush`, which didn't make sense, and that's what I was referring to, but I see that now it's fixed.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ah yes, sorry. Messed up and fixed it almost immediately. Obviously not almost enough.

Comment: @BoBTFish No worries. I'm fast :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No there are no special facilities for adding multiple space lines.
you can do this:

```
std::cout << "\n\n\n\n\n";
```

or this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  std::cout << "\n";
```

or implement your own `operator*`

```
std::string operator*(std::string const &s, std::size_t n)
{
  std::string r;
  r.reserve(n * s.size());
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    r += s;
  return r;
}

std::cout << (std::string("\n") * 5);
```

finally, recommended solution:

```
std::cout << std::string( 5, '\n' );
```

Comment: An overloaded operator for `std::string` just so you can add multiple newlines? The solution seems a bit disproportional to the problem. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Why define a special operator, when you can just write `std::string( 5, '\n' )`?  Otherwise: your `operator*` won't be found in namespaces other than the one in which it is defined and.  I'd define it in `std`: formally undefined behavior, but if it compilers (and it probably will), it will work.

Comment: Defining `operator *` for strings in this way is quite unreliable and probably unusable in any real application. (Oh, I see that there is already a comment to this effect! So I second @JamesKanze 's comment.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Thank you I completely forgot about this string constructor. In fact you are right I don't recommend the `operator*` solution either. The purpose was more to show it was possible...

Comment: @log0 It's possible (sort of, in some cases), but it's probably not something you'd want to do in production code.  Of course, if you're designing a new string class from scratch, it's something you'd definitely want to support.  (My pre-standard `String` class supported it.  It also defined a range as `[start, end)` (rather than `(start, len)`), and handled negative indexes as in Python.)

Answer (score 8):

You can write your own *manipulator*, that can insert multiple newlines at a time. Let's call it `mendl` (multiple endl):

```
class mendl
{
public:
    explicit mendl(unsigned int i) : n(i) {}
private:
    unsigned int n;

    template <class charT, class Traits>
    friend basic_ostream<charT,Traits>& operator<< (
                                         basic_ostream<charT,Traits>& os,
                                         const mendl& w)
    {
        // the manipulation: insert end-of-line characters and flush
        for (unsigned int i=0; i<w.n; i++)
            os << '\n';
        os.flush();
        return os;
    }
};
```

Usage is:

```
cout << "dfsdf" << mendl(4);
```

Comment: I believe there's a compile error in the `for(...)` line. That `n` should probably be `w.n`, should it not?

Comment: @yzt yes, of course. I made a [sample program](http://ideone.com/It5qLA) to test it.

Comment: @Alex `unsigned int n;` have type `unsigned int`, while `int i = 0` has `int` type. Change `int i=0` to `unsigned int i=0` or even better to `size_t`

Answer (score 3):

```
while(k--)cout<<"\n"; // k is number of lines you wanted
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always construct a string that has as many new-line characters (technically, LF) as you want, like so:

```
cout << "Whatever..." << string(42, '\n');
```

This will output 42 new lines after the "Whatever...". Another way, of course, is to define a new type (called e.g. `mendl` as [another one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17523749/383045) does.)

There are a multitude of things you can do, but the simplest and most straightforward is to use the above `std::string` constructor. But, you *might* need to `flush` your stream, depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider defining a constant variable if you are using a constant amount of newlines

for example,

```
const char nl5[] = "\n\n\n\n\n";
```

you may use it in the context of a cout like std::endl.

here is the entire code . . .

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    const char nl5[] = "\n\n\n\n\n";
    cout << "ln1" << nl5 << endl;
    cout << "ln2" << nl5 << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the standard library contains I and O methods but what's in the data stream is entirely up to you.

endl does half of what you asked for.  Calling it twice would get what you want.  Alternatively you could define a endl2x that puts out 2 newlines or have one that takes a parameter defining how many to emit

Answer (score -1):

you could try writing a function taking output stream and no of new lines to print returning the output stream